# Pass data to server via POST

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send data on button click with Angular 1.x.

Here is the debug from client-side, object seems to be set correctly:

[image]

Here is the debug from server-side, values are lost:

[image]

and my POCO:

```
[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This works but is rather ugly...

[image]

Can I get rid of the conversion and use the `Item` type as the parameter, instead of a `JObject`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert JavScript value to JSON string using [JSON.stringfy()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
$httpost.post("...", JSON.stringify($scope.newItem))
```

Comment: thanks but it's not working. I tried: http://i.imgur.com/XRazeah.png but still get null and 0s on server-side

Comment: Did you try with both JSON.stringify and [FromBody] from Mostafa's answer?

Comment: Could you change parameter type from ***Item*** to ***object***, and see if data is posted?

Comment: tried with both stringify and FromBody, same result still...I would like to keep my type and not use object, but I will try with dynamic maybe...

Comment: I do not mean permanently change it to object. Just for the sake of testing.

Comment: ok, just did it with dynamic and object. with dynamic I get Server error 500 and with object I see that a JObject is passed: http://i.imgur.com/E7k9vZP.png Why can't it be converted to my POCO?

Comment: I could not say for sure without look at your code. Well, it is not uncommon that default model binder sometime cannot bind, but it is not bad you just have to write one line of extra code to convert object to Item manually.

Comment: that's what I did (see update in question) but I don't like it...should be transparent :\

Answer (score 0):

use the `[FromBody]` :

```
public Add([FromBody] Item item) { ... }
```

For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter. This includes [FromBody], [FromUri], and [ModelBinder], or custom attributes.

Comment: also tried this (without JSON stringify) and still get the same wrong result

Answer (score 0):

Add the access modifier `public` in your class declaration.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: my POCO is already full public, just added it to my question. Thanks

Comment: I've noticed that you're sending a string instead of an integer in the `Key` property. Is it correct?

Comment: Key is a string yes, see my POCO definition in question